# Python Pillow Image.frombytes mode '1' bad result

Tags: python, image

Where am I wrong ? I want to create a basic white pict from bytes

```
from PIL import Image

if __name__ == "__main__":
    data = [chr(1)] * 8192
    data = "".join(data)
    im = Image.frombytes('1', (128,64), data, 'raw')
    im = im.convert("RGB")
    im.save("image.png", "PNG")
```

But I get this:

[image: but get this black/white strange pict]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In mode `1` each byte represents 8 pixels (there might be zero padding at end of each row if the width does not divide by 8). So to get a white image, you have to pass in only the byte `b'\xff'`

```
data = b'\xff' * 1024
im = Image.frombytes('1', (128,64), data)
```

Even if the Pillow docs say that there's one pixel per byte in this mode, that is *not true* for the `frombytes` and `tobytes` methods, at least.

Any other repeating input other than `\xff` (all white) or `\x00` (all black) will give some sort of pinstripe pattern, like the one in your question.

Comment: Thank you, that's what I thought, this feature does not take as it says 1-0 values for pixels.

Answer (score 4):

Just use `Image.new` instead:

```
im = Image.new(mode='RGB', size=(128,64), color=(255,255,255))
```

If you really want to make it from bytes, it would be like this:

```
Image.frombytes(mode='RGB', size=(128,64), data=b'\xff'*128*64*3)
```

**edit**: `Image.frombytes` expects bytes, not a list of integers.  To convert a list of integers to the right type, use this:

```
>>> bytes([0,1,2])  # Python 3
b'\x00\x01\x02'

>>> bytes(bytearray([0,1,2]))  # Python 2
'\x00\x01\x02'
```

**edit 2**:  mode='1' or the docs have bug (see comment thread).   Assuming you have a list of zeros and ones, 1024 elements long, and you want to convert this to an 128x64 monochromatic image (one bit per pixel) then you'll have to pack the bytes manually:

```
bits = [int(not (y%13 and x%7)) for x in range(64) for y in range(128)]  
# asymmetric grid
octets = [bits[i:i+8] for i in range(0, len(bits), 8)]

def bits2byte(bits8):
    result = 0
    for bit in bits8:
        result <<= 1
        result |= bit
    return result

data = bytes(bytearray([bits2byte(octet) for octet in octets]))
im = Image.frombytes(mode='1', size=(128,64), data=data)
im.show()
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: I have an array of integers [1, 1, 0, 1.....] to convert to an image, but it seems I can't create it with Image.frombytes why ?
My question contains it's only a test that does not work either

Comment: Because `Image.frombytes` expects bytes, not a list of integers.  You can use `bytes([1, 1, 0, 1])` to convert it.

Comment: I know, it works perfectely with mode "L" or "RGB" and 0-255 or rgb values converted to bytes however with mode "1" and 0-1 or 0-255 values converted to bytes it still does not work. Maybe there is an argument to add ?

Comment: If you really want to use mode='1', why do you convert to RGB in the question?  Anyway, added example for mode='1'.

Comment: With mode "1" one byte represents multiple pixels.

Comment: @HåkenLid  No, it's 1-bit pixels (i.e. black and white image) [stored with one pixel per byte](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/handbook/concepts.html#modes).  In comparison, mode='L' is 8-bit pixels i.e. grayscale image.

Comment: I think the docs are wrong. Look at the image in the question. The byte `\x01` represents the bits `00000001`, which gives lines of seven black pixels and one white pixel.

Comment: Hmm, yep, looks like either docs are wrong or PIL mode='1' has bug.  I only needed a 1024 length byte string to fill 8192 size image.  Well whatever it is `\xff` will give a white image.